# Do I seriously need to install Xcode and compile PyObjC as a result of 1.7.6 update?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

There must be an easier way.

I get this warning when attempting to start my app today:

> /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/file_watcher.py:97:
>
> UserWarning: Detecting source code changes is not supported because your Python version does not include PyObjC (http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/). Please install PyObjC or, if that is not practical, file a bug at http://code.google.com/p/appengine-devappserver2-experiment/issues/list.

Comment: I've tried installing the latest version of PyObjC using MacPorts and I still get this warning.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653153/install-pyobjc-on-python-2-6-on-os-x-10-5

Comment: What version of Python do you have?

Comment: This page looks pretty useful:
http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/install.html
Note that you DON'T need to install Xcode to get a compiler. If you sign up for a free Apple Developer account, you can download just the command line tools, which are just a couple of hundred MB, rather than 4 GB.

Comment: Just search this page for the command line tools.
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PyObjC installer only requires Xcode because it requires a compiler. However, you can easily get a compiler without downloading Xcode.

Just [click this link](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/), and sign in with your Apple Developer ID, or register for a free Apple Developer Account if you don't already have one. Then search the page for the Command Line Tools, download them, and install them.

Once you have installed the Command Line Tools, you can install PyObjC using the [instructions on the website](http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/install.html).

The website details how to install using either `pip`, `easy_install`, or manually. I will briefly outline the first two methods below (manual installation is slightly more involved, and you should read the instructions on the site.):

#### pip:

```
env CC=clang pip install -U pyobjc-core
env CC=clang pip install -U pyobjc
```

#### easy_install:

```
easy_install -U pyobjc-core
easy_install -U pyobjc
```

#### manual installation:

[Scroll to the end of this webpage, and read the pertinent information.](http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/install.html)

Comment: Also note that if you are deploying as an app, you need to make sure that the Python version you are using to build the app is itself built with the correct `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` for your earliest targeted system. The easiest way to ensure this is to build the app on an old system like 10.6. Generally the apps will work on newer systems, but it is more fiddly to get them to work on systems older than those they were build on. Again, read the documentation at the end of (this page)[http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/install.html].