# PyDev Breakpoints in App Engine 1.7.6 broken?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, python-2.7, pydev, breakpoints

I just upgraded to the App Engine 1.7.6 SDK for my python app and realised that breakpoints no longer work in [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) (Eclipse plugin) when using the new `dev_appserver.py`.

Does anyone know of a way of enabling them again? I assume the new server is spawning a new process for the web server, and the debugger isn't attaching to that one. I'm not sure how to configure it to do that though.

In the meantime I am using the `old_dev_appserver.py` server.

Comment: By "no longer work" I mean the breakpoints aren't being triggered in the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: I was just about to ask the same question

Comment: I have submitted an issue on AppEngine project: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9012

Comment: Is this somehow related to the new pyobjc warning?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513642/do-i-seriously-need-to-install-xcode-and-compile-pyobjc-as-a-result-of-1-7-6-upd

Comment: I'm not sure but I am on osx and have xcode installed. The server works fine, it is just breakpoints in pydev that do not.

Comment: I can confirm what you're seeing: with SDK version 1.7.6 breakpoints are not being hit in Eclipse with PyDev and that using old_dev_appserver.py does seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: Ditto here, Windows 7, Eclipse 4.2, PyDev 2.7.3, GAE 1.7.6.
Breakpoints are not being hit. I tried the suggestion to call MonkeyPatchPdb, that did not help either. Not sure how it was supposed to help. I do not put pdb.set_trace() calls in my code. I rely on PyDev interactive debugging.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UPDATE 2012-07-27:

Following the comment, I verified, the issue is solved after updating to
PyDev. 2.8 and App Engine 1.8.2

OBSOLETE:

I found the following analysis of the problem at [googleappengine issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=9027)

> The reason why PDB doesn't work is because dev_appserver is using
>   stdin/stdout for interprocess communication. Python has built-in
>   libraries for IPC: http://docs.python.org/2/library/ipc.html. 
>   dev_appserver should use these, and then stdin/stdout can be left
>   alone so that PDB still works.

So it seems that there is no workaround, rather than reverting to use old_dev_appserver.py

UPDATE 2013-04-23:
Inability to debug is annoying.
Many developers complain about it

1. [PyDev Breakpoints in App Engine 1.7.6 broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514743/pydev-breakpoints-in-app-engine-1-7-6-broken)
2. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/ep5BWYKpQpU
3. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/TCQuJpF44cY
4. https://code.google.com/p/appengine-devappserver2-experiment/issues/detail?id=28
5. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9012

I am keeping track of the development of this issue here:
http://goo.gl/XRU01

Comment: Just to note, PyDev 2.8.0 is now supporting the new hooks on Google App Engine, so, debugging should be working again.

See release details at: http://pydev.org/

Comment: I had the same problem as Dylan, and I confirm it is solved with PyDev 2.8.

Comment: Thanks for update, seems we have enough evidence to conclude that the issue is **finally** resolved. Personally I think it is a shame it took so long.

Comment: This is still broken for me, after updating both GAE and PyDev to the latest versions.  I even tried reinstalling Eclipse, PyDev, and GAE.  Simply changing the target back to 'old_dev_appserver.py' fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, ran into the same problem.

Open your Run/Debug Configuration and set the Main Module to:

```
${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/old_dev_appserver.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean pdb.set_trace() isn't working?

Look for the function MonkeyPatchPdb() in google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py

Run that somewehere in your own project before you use pdb and it should fix it.

Comment: MonkeyPatchPdb doesn't seem to exist in the new dev_appserver.py. I am not sure if PyDev uses Pdb, I am just setting breakpoints in the Eclipse IDE. I did try using pdb.set_trace though, and it caused the script to quit.

Comment: Is it how it supposed to work: putting the code below in your /main.py ?

    from google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver import MonkeyPatchPdb
    import pdb
    MonkeyPatchPdb(pdb)