# How to debug Google App Engine 1.8.x python27 with PyDev and Eclipse (set breakpoints)

Tags: google-app-engine

I found that in new dev_appserver dubugging is not possible and old_app_devserver need to be used.

As I found in previous version 1.7.x is because probable invalid use of stdin and stdout - what is changed in 1.8.x or still the same problem. [PyDev Breakpoints in App Engine 1.7.6 broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514743/pydev-breakpoints-in-app-engine-1-7-6-broken)

What is other debug possibility options (IDEs) mean setting breakpoints not logging only.

Comment: I use Boa constructor with remote debugging, with the new dev server.  There is a new command line for the dev server `---python_startup_script` which is run prior to server startup and is not sandboxed.  I know nothing about PyDev remote debugging but this is where I would investigate it.

Comment: PyDev is excellent plugin for Eclipse for Python development which it use `pydev debugger: starting`. Many people using PyDev since it allow work with extreme large code bases (500k lines) - it is need support for this.

Comment: I will probably never use Eclipse (thats why I don't know anything about PyDev), I am always running on low power low memory VM's.  Not sure why no one has done it for PyDev yet.  It should be do-able.  It took all of 15 minutes to get it working with Boa, so give it a try.

Comment: Eclipse is very powerfull and I am need it for large project. Cost of migration whole project it to high to make try - including migration custom plugins. I can check BOA with new project. Looking on screenshots I am not sure if it can handle 500k lines of code and 1k files - maybe I am wrong I need check it.

Comment: BTW can you paste link to BOA constructor - I found this but it looks that project is dead http://www.ohloh.net/p/boa-constructor/commits/summary.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/cwt/boa-constructor  Boa Constructor was forked late last year.  And yes it doesn't get a lot of love.

Comment: I am not suggesting your change from eclipse for your project.  You could in a pinch just use it for debugging, if you can't get PyDev working, though I am not sure why anyone hasn't bothered sorting it out yet. The largest project I have in Boa is about 500 source files and 260k lines of code - no problems there ;-)

Comment: Oh and one last thing, Boa is actually useable on a raspberrypi with 256MB ;-)

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-appengine/boa/google-appengine/-m00Qz4Vc7U/GkBiH1hWK8cJ

Comment: Just to note, PyDev 2.8.0 is now supporting the new hooks on Google App Engine, so, debugging should be working again. See release details at: http://pydev.org/